# Android Replacing Listview with Image if no Results

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am trying to implement a function were by if the cursor populating the listview is empty an image will be displayed instead of the listview.

I have tried putting in the image but it is with above or below the list view and ruins the layout

I am using a listFragment at the moment but my problem is positioning the image. How do I place it so that the image is 'invisible' until it is called?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/filterButton"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/floatingButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Code**

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)
                        {
                            //call to populate the image?
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry no match, please refine search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        else
                        {
                             //display list as normal

                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an imageview to your xml
set its visibility to gone.

in your cursor -if empty set `imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `listView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`
do the opposite in your happy condition.

dont forget to initialize the variables imageView and listView beforehand by their ids.

**your xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/yourpicture"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/imageview"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/filterButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/floatingButton" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**your code**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){

        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }else{
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @yUdoDis answer, but I recommend a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html).

Your layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/yourpicture"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"/>

</ViewSwitcher>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/filterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/floatingButton" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your activity code:

```
ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
    switcher.setDisplayedChild(1);
}else{
    switcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, ran into some issues so went with yUdoDis answer, plus one though!

Comment: i really like the concept of using viewswitcher...here take my cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ListView visibility to GONE and the image view to VISIBLE when there's no data. Do the opposite when there is data.

Alternatively you can use the setEmptyView API of the list adapter.